# Microsoft Graph SDK 5 upgrade - How to pass a FieldValueSet

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I'm struggling upgrading to Microsoft SDK 5.3.0.
This code is suppose to set a value to a specific column for a DriveItem.

```
string key = "SomeColHeader";
string value = "Value1";
             
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet
{
  AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
  {
    {key, value}
  }
};

await GraphClient
   .Drives[driveId]
   .Items[driveItemId]
   .ListItem.Fields
   .Request()
   .UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet)
```

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, it's definitely a bug in v 5.3.0 that it's not possible to update FieldValueSet when you access the list item through the endpoint

```
PATCH /v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{driveItemId}/listItem
```

As an alternative get `listItem` and select `parentReference` and `sharepointIds` properties. Then access `listItem` through `/sites` endpoint

```
var listItem = await client
           .Drives[driveId]
           .Items[driveItemId]
           .ListItem.GetAsync(x=>
           {
               x.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "id", "parentReference", "sharepointIds" }; 
           });

var result = await client.Sites[listItem.ParentReference.SiteId]
          .Lists[listItem.SharepointIds.ListId]
          .Items[listItem.Id]
          .Fields
          .PatchAsync(fieldValueSet);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Let's hope this SDK gets a little more mature in the coming months and that the documentation improves.